# Play sound in mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry, audio

I want to make myself a web based stop watch for training that I can use on my Blackberry mobile browser.

The stopwatch should count 3 minutes, then ring a bell, wait 1 minute, then ring another bell and then repeat.

My problem is I can't seem to get sound to work on my blackberry browser.

I tried using `<embed src="bell.wav">` which works fine in the browser of a normal computer, but it doesn't make a sound on my blackberry.

Should I build this stopwatch with Javascript and HTML or should I build it with flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [BlackBerry HTML Reference](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11848/Overview_alphabetic_573957_11.jsp), the EMBED tag isn't supported.  You might want to experiment with the OBJECT tag.  One example I've seen to play embedded video in the browser is something like this:

```
<object height="288" width="352"
data="http://admin.example.com/_ipvideos/video_file_35.3gp"
type="video/3gpp" />
```

Something similar might work for simple audio files, too.

As for Flash, you're out of luck as none of the current BlackBerry browsers don't support it.  If you're not having luck doing this in a webpage, you might want to bite the bullet and write a native app to do it.  Or give [BlackBerry Widgets](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/browserdev/) a try.